# storage-resize-images: Cloud Storage trigger bucket [BUCKET NAME] not found

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-extensions

I tried to install the [storage-resize-images](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/storage-resize-images) extension, but received the following error:

> Error occurred while deploying resources: RESOURCE_ERROR:
>   /deployments/firebase-ext-storage-resize-images/resources/generateResizedImage
>   {"ResourceType":"gcp-types/cloudfunctions-v1:projects.locations.functions","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":"Cloud
>   Storage trigger bucket *[MY BUCKET NAME]* not found"}

Answer (score 1):

The key part of that error message is:

> **Cloud Storage trigger bucket *[MY BUCKET NAME]* not found**

There are a couple of possible causes:

1. Cloud Storage for Firebase isn't set up in the project yet, so the bucket doesn't exist. To check if this is the case, head to the *Storage* tab of the Firebase console. If you see *Get Started* instead of a view of a Storage bucket, click *Get Started* to create the default bucket.

   1. If you want to use a different bucket with the extension, click the three-dot menu in the top right corner of the Storage explorer, and click *Add Bucket*.
2. The bucket name is malformed. It needs to be of the form `[bucket-name].appspot.com`. For example, `my-bucket.appspot.com`